# Oracle MySQL equivalent code

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, pagination

What would be the equivalent Oracle(11g) code for performing following operation:

> For MySQL

```
ps = con.prepareStatement("select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS from student_details where UPPER(name) like UPPER(?) limit " + offset + ", " + noOfRecords);
```

and `rs = ps.executeQuery("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (select t.*, rownum rn, count(*) over() as SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
        from student_details t
       where UPPER(name) like UPPER(?))
WHERE rn <= offset
```

The value returned in "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS" will be the number of records that would have been selected if there wasn't the `WHERE rn <= offset` clause

Answer (score 0):

The only two RDBMS-specific things I see in your statement are "upper()" and "limit".

Here's a link for using Oracle "rownum" as a workaround for "limit":

- https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=415724.

"Upper()" should work fine as-is in Oracle.

Comment: also SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS might be better as count(*)

Comment: What about SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and SELECT FOUND_ROWS()?